# Import classes with all dependencies Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a Android application which is able to send and receive messages from TextSecure.
For doing that, I am using the libtextsecure and libaxolotl.

For storing the Session information, IndentityKey information and so, I need 4 storage classes:

- sessionStore
- preKeyStore
- signedPreKeyStore
- identityStore

There are interfaces for that in libaxolotl but I do not want to implement these storage classes on my own. The aim would be to use the already finished class of TextSecure:

- TextSecureAxolotlStore

Github source: https://github.com/WhisperSystems/TextSecure/blob/5602a3dfc0501e97b605b1838634d8db1ef5f013/src/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/crypto/storage/TextSecureAxolotlStore.java

But i don' want to use the whole TextSecure project as a library, because I just don't need the whole functionality, I just need this one class!

Now here is the question: is it possible to just copy the TextSecureAxolotlStorewith all the dependencies within the project itself to my own project? I can view all the dependencies within android studio but I am not able to copy and paste them to my project.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can easily unpack the JAR file, and copy that class into your classpath, or delete all the other files out of the JAR.

Comment: well of course I can but then I am missing all the dependencies. The TextSecureAxolotlStore depends on more than 100 classes within the TextSecure project...

Comment: " I can view all the dependencies" If you can view the dependencies, keep those aswell.

Comment: Those dependencies are other classes within TextSecure. I would need to copy every single class to my project. And every new class depends on other classes within the TextSecure project. Do you know what I mean? I am not talking about external dependencies, just internal class dependencies.

Comment: I know. If you don't want to have the whole JAR, thats what you have to do.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Andorid Studio to not compile the whole TextSecure project again and again and to just compile and check the classes which I use within my project?

Comment: None that I know of.